# Why do I not see changes to my Label's Text between method calls?

Tags: c#, methods

I have a button with the following code:

```
private void install_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    installcover.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    loading_text.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    back_btn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    install_btn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

    loading_text.Text = "Connecting to server...";
    mapDriveX();

    loading_text.Text = "Copying test tools from server...";
    CopyTestTools();

    loading_text.Text = "Installing Drivers...";
    installDrivers();

    loading_text.Text = "Disconnecting...";
    unMapDriveX();

    loading_text.Text = "Restarting...";
    Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /t 10");
}
```

It looks like it tries to launch all of them at the same time.

Even if I put `Thread.Sleep(5000);` between lines it still goes without waiting.

It doesn't change text one after another one; all I can see at the end is the result of the command:

```
 loading_text.Text = "Restarting...";
```

Comment: What's your question, then?

Comment: Doesn't look strange to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "it looks like"? What exactly are you observing? And what do those methods do? It sounds like you're almost certainly doing too much work on the UI thread...

Comment: What do the methods `mapDriveX`, `CopyTestTools` etc do? Are they synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: We would need to see the code for the `mapDriveX()`, `CopyTestTools()`, `installDrivers()` and `unMapDriveX()` methods. It looks like one or all of them is failing, which cascades failure to the other methods.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar it doesn't change text one after another one

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title. StackOverflow is, in the long run, meant as an archive of problems and solutions. Someone encountering your problem in the future isn't likely to search for "strange behavior" :)

Comment: changed title.
i just want 5sec pause after mapDriveX();

Comment: @arti: Of course not - the UI thread is blocked the entire time and has no chance to update the UI. Either make the entire thing multi-threaded or add `Application.DoEvents()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing all work on UI thread syncrhonously. So it will wait to update UI until `install_btn_Click` has finished.

You need to use e.g. BackgroundWorker which works on another thread, with some calls to UI thread only when needed to update the text.

Comment: [How to: Use a Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks, i moved everything what i want to proper methods and now all is ok :)

Answer (score 8):

No, this is the expected behaviour. Refreshing the UI is done via the paint event; it can't process the paint event until your method *finishes*. If you want things to be done in the background, look into things like `BackgroundWorker`, `ThreadPool` or `Task`. Keep in mind that any work done on a worker **cannot talk to the UI** - and needs to specifically request access back via `Control.Invoke` / `Control.BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 1):

So other people have mentioned that you should be doing you work on another thread which is true, but no one has mentioned async/await which is the new way of doing asynchronous processing in .NET. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) is the msdn resource for it. The idea is that you call your async processes that will take time and await them in the original method, to keep the method from continuing until the process has completed. [This](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) is also a good source.

Comment: If they do it the way it is currently being done, yes. Each process is in its own method and the UI updates are in between. So each method should be made async and awaited.